# User Registry Management in IBM Docker Container Cloud

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

since we can upload images to a private registry in the IBM Docker Container Cloud I'm wondering on how the collaboration works. Can I give access to private images to other users/groups? If so, how can you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can invite other Bluemix users under 'Manage Organizations' and then 'Invite A User' to any of your Bluemix spaces.